# Rotating list not working?

Tags: python

Running the following python code:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = list(marbles) 
        print(marbles)
    def switch(self):
        self.input[1], self.input[0] = self.input[0], self.input[1]
        #print self.input
    def rotate(self):
        return self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
        #print self.input
    def is_solved(self):
        if all(self.input[i] <= self.input[i+1] for i in range(len(self.input)-1)):
            return True
            print "True"
        else:
            print "Not solved!"

board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
board.switch()
print board.input
board.rotate()
print board.input

board.is_solved()
```

doesn't seem to work. The board.switch() method works correctly when called; however, the rotate method, doesn't work (output board.input attribute is the same as the input board.input attribute).

Comment: What is the expected answer you are looking for? Did you mean to reverse the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current state, your `rotate` function never saves itself back into `self.input`. You simply return the new state.

```
def rotate(self):
    return self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
```

It should be changed to this (similar to what you do in your `switch` function):

```
def rotate(self):
    self.input = self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
```

Then, your rotation will be saved.

Comment: crystal clear explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your code is failing because you are discarding the new list you create in your `rotate` method. However, you might consider using a `collections.deque` instead of a list:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(range(10))
>>> d
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> d.rotate(-1)
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Note, this works in-place. This is more efficiently implemented in a `deque`, since it is a doubly-linked list whereas `list` is actually an array-list.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the rotated list instead of reassigning it back to `self.input`:

```
def rotate(self):
    self.input = self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the class object (input) itself then change as been suggested above.

If you don't need to update it because once you update then all other functions will also get changed which you might not liked.

So do this -

```
rotated_board = board.rotate()
print(rotated_board)
```

Let me know, if it worked!